# DUXCameraSettingsController seems to be broken in UXSDK 4.8.x

Tags: dji-sdk

After upgrading to the 4.8.x SDK from 4.7.1 the DUXCameraSettingsController stopped displaying the actual settings panels, but continues to show the settings tab-bar, pressing the tabs does not make any settings appear. Is this a bug in the UXSDK or am I just using the controller wrong? I cannot find any example on the usage of that particular controller.

```
- (UIView *)view
{
  UIView *view = [UIView new];
  DUXCameraSettingsController *ctrl = [DUXCameraSettingsController cameraSettingsController];
  ctrl.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
  ctrl.view.frame = view.frame;
  [view addSubview:ctrl.view];
  [ctrl.view.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:view.topAnchor].active = YES;
  [ctrl.view.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:view.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
  [ctrl.view.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:view.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
  [ctrl.view.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:view.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
  [ctrl didMoveToParentViewController:nil];
  return view;
}
```

Comment: Which aircraft or camera are you connected to when seeing this?

Comment: I have tested this with a mavic pro and a spark drone with the same result.

Comment: You'll need to add `DUXCameraSettingsController` as a child view controller to the view controller you're using. For more information on child view controller see here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html under `Adding a Child View Controller to Your Content`

Comment: thanks, that helped me a lot :)